Tail supremum of an $l^1$ sequence
Suppose that $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a positive sequence and $(a_n)_{n\geq 0} \in l^1$.
Let $A_N = sup_{j \geq N}a_j$ denote the sequence of tail suprema.
If there is a constant $c \geq 1$ so that
$$\frac{1}{c}\leq \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq c$$
Is $A_N$ also in $l^1$?
Without the bounds on the ratio, this is not the case, e.g. if $b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $a_n$ is defined by
$$a_k = \begin{cases}b_n & n \neq k^2 \\ \frac{1}{k} & n = k^2 \end{cases}$$
Note that $A_N$ is constant on blocks $[0,n_1], [n_{1}+1, n_2], ..., $
So $\sum_{N \geq 0}A_N = n_1A_1 + n_2A_2 + ... $ If there is a counterexample, the blocks must be unbounded.

I think the answer is no. I'll post a counter-example shortly.

Let $c=2.$ Define the sequence $(a_n)$ as follows.
$$a_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2^{10+n}} & 1\leq n\leq 485 \\
\frac{1}{2^{981-n}} & 486\leq n\leq 980 \\
\frac{1}{2^{n-979}} & 981\leq n\leq 1000\\
\end{cases}$$
Thus $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{1000} a_n \approx 1,$ whilst $\displaystyle\sum_{N=1}^{1000} A_N \approx \frac{1000}{2}.$ Next,
$$a_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2^{-979+n}} & 1001\leq n\leq 500,470 \\
\frac{1}{2^{999,962-n}} & 500,471\leq n\leq 999,960 \\
\frac{1}{2^{n-999,958}} & 999,961\leq n\leq 1,000,000\\
\end{cases}$$
Thus $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1001}^{1,000,000} a_n \approx \frac{1}{2},$ whilst $\displaystyle\sum_{N=1001}^{1,000,000} A_N \approx \frac{1,000,000}{4}.$
Continuing in this way, we can make $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1,000,001}^{1,000,000,000} a_n \approx \frac{1}{4},$ whilst $\displaystyle\sum_{N=1,000,001}^{1000,000,000} A_N \approx \frac{1,000,000,000}{8}.$
And so on.
